# Issue in setting date in datepicker in Android

Tags: android, datepicker, uidatepicker

I have 1 problem regarding Date Picker in Android.

I have 2 date pickers:

1. For start date
2. For end date.

In start date I want to set 1st date of current month. And in end date I want to set current date (i.e. today's date). I have set it and even I get Transaction like that dates... starting from 1st date to the current date. And even I can see in console date as 1st as start date and 25 (i.e. today's date) as the end date.

But In Date Picker I can see current date only in both. As start date and end date. That means I get output from 1st date to current date but in Date Picker I can see current date only in both Date Picker.

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Code is:

```
Date sDate=new Date(dp_startdate.getYear()-1900,dp_startdate.getMonth(),1);     
Date eDate=new Date(dp_enddate.getYear()-1900,dp_enddate.getMonth(),dp_enddate.getDayOfMonth());        
System.out.println("Sdate:"+sDate.toString());
System.out.println("EDate:"+eDate.toString());

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String startDate=formatter.format(sDate);
String endDate=formatter.format(eDate);

System.out.println("start Date is:"+startDate);
System.out.println("end Date is:"+endDate);

Bundle bundle=new Bundle();

bundle.putString("startDate", startDate);
bundle.putString("endDate", endDate);

System.out.println("start Date is:"+startDate);
System.out.println("start Date is:"+endDate);
```

Please help me.

Comment: Use the [DatePicker.init()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) to set the date on DatePicker.

Comment: @Mudassir..Thanks a lot..I tried it..in so many ways..but I get exception..

Comment: dp_startdate.init(startyear, startmonth, startdate, new OnDateChangedListener() {
   
   public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
     int dayOfMonth) 
   {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dp_startdate=view;
    startyear=year;
    startmonth=monthOfYear;
    startdate=dayOfMonth;
    
   }
  });

Comment: dp_enddate.init(endyear, endmonth, enddate, null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this-->

```
    dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = 1;

            dp.setVisibility(1);

            dp.init(year, month, day, null);




            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            s.append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
            .append(year).append(" ");

            Toast.makeText(Datepicker.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });


}


   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />



    </LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: Pasted xml as well

Like u said u want one datepicker to be fixed to the current month's first date,So instead of getting value of day from system's calender(which will give u the current one, you can explicitly put whatever int value there.

Then u can use this value i.e i have used the custom date value in toast..